# Entity Framework ListObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I got a simple function which returns a List of DatabaseViewName

```
public List<DatabaseViewName> GetAllItems(string article)
    {
        List<DatabaseViewName> visi;

        var cus = from s in _entities.DatabaseViewName where
        s.articleNr == article select s;
        visi = new List<DatabaseViewName>(cus);

        return visi;
    }
```

The first run is fine. I get a List with desired Objects.

[image: FirstArticle]

The 2nd run, with a different article (with more properties) still contains the 5 list items from the first run. Not additionally!! Only the Value of the Properties stays...
I KNOW WHY but can't fix it! The Code is correct, pls don't try to tell me something else.
The EntityFrameworke Cache the information to save time. I need to disable this Caching... How?

[image: SecArticle]

Thanks!

PS: Doesn't matter List<> or Array

see the problem is this:

```
var ese = (from s in _entities.DataBbseViewName where 
s.ArticleNr == article select s).ToArray();
```

in "ese" the Value didn't change. I can run it 100times with 100 different articles.
The first-run values will be saved.

Comment: How many records are there in database for the two different articles?

Comment: and how many items are you getting in cus when you run 2nd time?

Comment: is it possible that you look at the first instance of `visi` the second time too? (You don't mutate the list - you just return it - btw: don't return lists - return immutable stuff like arrays or the new read-only lists)

Comment: 1 time in cus,
And no i don't look at the first instance.

Comment: What does the code look like that you use to call the GetAllItems(string article) method with?

Comment: Based on your debug screen shots, it looks like the 1st run returned 5 items and the 2nd run returned 18 items.  Where is it you're looking that the list "didn't change"?  Is this in a UI or a calling Method?

Comment: @Jontatas ??? Nothing to do with the call

Comment: @Adam47 First Article has 5 items with properties
2nd Article has 18 items with diffrent properties

As you can see in screenshot Nr.2 The Value of the First Item is the same es in Screenshot one. That shouldn't happen! Because in the Database they are totally different

Comment: I'M receiving cached values

Comment: First. Fix your language. You are overly agressive. Calm down. Second. There is not enough information. How is your DB and EF setup? Did you try creating new project and replicating the problem? Are different tables doing the same thing or just this one? Did you check the raw data in DB? Are you doing this in single or different sessions?

Comment: @Euphoric Fix your reading skills. Your questions have nothing in common with the problem. I know the problem, I ask for one thing, How to disable the Caching. I dont need to change my Code or check my DB for the 100000001 time.  See that is agressive

Comment: Your problem is not EF caching.  Caching does not append results for subsequent queries.  It can prevent you from getting updated information.  Perhaps you should include the code that calls GetAllItems.  Also, why is s.articleNr the same as ArtikelNr?  The screenshot doesn't seem to match the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
You can set the Query to no Tracking!

```
var ese = (from s in _entities.DataBbseViewName where
s.ArticleNr == article select s).ToArray().AsNoTracking();
```

Seeya